# does emacs has rational number data type

Tags: emacs, elisp

I eval a lisp expression in *scratch*

```
(+ (/ 1 2) (/ 1 2))
```

I got a 0.

normally it should be 1.

Comment: Didn't you just answer the question yourself?

Answer (score 9):

As Oleg points out, operators usually default to integer arithmetic unless you include floating point arguments (like `1.0`).

With respect to your question about rational number support, emacs-calc (which is part of emacs) supports many number types including fractions (i.e. rational numbers), complex numbers, infinite precision integers, etc. Your code must call emacs-calc functions (instead of `/`, etc.) in order to use calc's arithmetic.

GNU Emacs Calc Manual:

- [Fractions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Fractions)
- [Index of Lisp Math Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Lisp-Function-Index)

Comment: Ah, `calc` to the rescue yet again. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way

```
(+ (/ 1.0 2) (/ 1.0 2))
```

According to [emacs doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Arithmetic-Operations.html)

> Function: / dividend divisor &rest divisors
>
> if all the arguments are integers, then the result is an integer too.

Comment: That fails to answer the question, although between the lines, you can infer that because Emacs uses floats, it doesn't have a separate type for real numbers. (Many Lisp implementations have one; that is, 1/3 is represented precisely, rather than as a floating-point approximation.)

Answer (score 1):

You can read all about numbers in elisp here:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Numbers` <kbd>RET</kbd>

As already indicated by tripleee, it is apparent that the answer is "no".

Comment: ...except that, as per Juancho's answer, the `calc` library makes that a "yes".

Answer (score 0):

Emacs `calc` has rational data type: use colon, like `1:2 == 0.5` or `5:3 == 1 + 2:3 == 1:2:3`.

This way Emacs `calc` simplifies expressions, for example if you deal with display resolutions for `1920:1080` it prints `16:9`! If you want 1440p with the 16:9 ratio: `1440 * 16:9` ⇒ `2560`.